# Is it safe to pass lambda to function that is going out of scope (lambda executes after the method returns)?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am learning C++ so maybe my question is dumb. I am creating a function that takes a lambda as a parameter. I just want to know if its safe to call it when the lambda function goes out of scope. With code is easier to explain what I mean:

```cpp
struct SomeStruct
{
    // store pointer to callback function
    void (*callback)(bool);
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
};

void some_method(int arg1, int arg2, void (*on_complete_callback)(bool))
{
   SomeStruct s;
   s.callback = on_complete_callback;
   s.arg1 = arg1;
   s.arg2 = arg2;

   // this helper class will copy the struct even though it is passed by reference
   SomeHelperClass->SomeQueue.enqueue( &s );

   // do work on a separate task/thread
   SomeHelperClass->CreateThread([](){
    
       // get copy of struct
       SomeStruct s_copy;

       SomeHelperClass->SomeQueue.dequeue( &s_copy );
  

       // do work that takes time to complete

       // IS IT SAFE TO CALL THIS CALLBACK FUNCTION?
       s_copy.callback(true);

   });
}
```

**So my question is given that code if its safe to have something like this?**

```
void method_1()
{
    void (*foo)(bool) = [](bool completedCorrectly)
    {
        cout << "task completed :" << completedCorrectly << endl;
    };

    some_method(1,2,foo);

    // at this point foo should be deleted no? 
    // why does this work if foo is executed after method_1 completes and its stack is deleted?
    // can I have code like that?
}
```

---

### Edit 2

Here is the same question with working code instead of pseudo code:

```
#include <iostream>     //for using cout
using namespace std;    //for using cout

// 3 pointers
int* _X; // points to integer
int* _Y; // points to integer
void (*_F)(int); // points to function


void print_values()
{
    cout << "x=" << *_X << " and y=" << *_Y << endl;
}

void some_function()
{
    // create variables that live on stack of some_function
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    void (*foo)(int) = [](int someInt)
    {
        cout << "value passed to lambda is:" << someInt << endl;
    };

    // point global variables to variables created on this stack x,y and foo
    _X = &x;
    _Y = &y;
    _F = foo;

    // works
    _F(11);

    // works
    print_values();

    // when exiting variables x,y and foo should be deleted
}

int main(void)
{
    // call some function
    some_function();

    // DOES NOT WORK (makes sense)
    print_values();

    // WHY DOES THIS WORK? WHY FOO IS NOT DISTROYED LIKE X AND Y?
    _F(10); 

    return 0;
}
```

**If I where to call that method many times and each time with a different lambda will it work? Will the callback method call the correct lambda every time?**

Comment: Your function takes a function pointer, not a lambda.

Comment: You are correct @n.'pronouns'm. . I should rename that with a function pointer perhaps.

Comment: If you take a lambda there's a mechanism for ensuring that all dependent objects are included in that "package". That's what the `[]` definition is for.

Comment: A function does not live on the stack, even if a function pointer that points to it is obtained from a lambda.

Comment: So is it safe to code like that? If I call that method many times every time with a different lambda will it always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda expression is like a class. It is a blueprint for instantiating objects. Classes exist only in source code. A program actually works with objects created from the blueprint defined by a class. Lambda expressions are a source code blueprint for creating closures. Each lambda expression is transformed into a class by the compiler and instantiated into an object called closure. This class has the ability to capture values (that's that the `[]` part does) and take parameters (that's that the `()` part does) for its call operator.

Here is an example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    auto l = [i](int const x){std::cout << x+i << '\n';};
  
    l(2);
}
```

The compiler transforms this into something similar to the following (generated with https://cppinsights.io/).

```cpp
int main()
{
  int i = 42;
    
  class __lambda_6_11
  {
    public: 
    inline /*constexpr */ void operator()(const int x) const
    {
      std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(x + i), '\n');
    }
    
    private: 
    int i;
    
    public:
    __lambda_6_11(int & _i)
    : i{_i}
    {}
    
  };
  
  __lambda_6_11 l = __lambda_6_11{i};
  l.operator()(2);
}
```

You can see here a class that implements the call operator (`operator()`) with an `int` argument. You can also see the constructor taking an argument of type `int`. And then you can see the instantiation of this class at the end of main and the invocation of its call operator.

I hope this helps you understand better how lambdas work.